# Map.get cannot retrieve value with string keys

Tags: elixir

I'm having a strange issue with `Map`s. Here's a small example to reproduce the behaviour:

```
defmodule Document do

  @expiration_presets_to_timeshift %{
    "immediately": [seconds: 1],
    "1-minute": [minutes: 1],
    "1-hour": [hours: 1],
    "1-day": [days: 1],
    "1-week": [weeks: 1],
    "1-month": [months: 1],
    "1-year": [years: 1],
    "never": [years: 9999],
  }

  def expiration_presets, do: @expiration_presets_to_timeshift
end
```

If we then try to retrieve information from the map:

```
iex(1)> import Document
Document
iex(2)> Document.expiration_presets
%{"1-day": [days: 1], "1-hour": [hours: 1], "1-minute": [minutes: 1],
"1-month": [months: 1], "1-week": [weeks: 1], "1-year": [years: 1],
immediately: [seconds: 1], never: [years: 9999]}
iex(3)> Document.expiration_presets["1-hour"]
nil
iex(4)> Map.get(Document.expiration_presets, "1-hour")
nil
```

I notice two strange behaviors:

1. The "immediately" and "never" keys have become atoms. I never asked for this. Why ?
2. I can't seem to retrieve the value using the key strings (`Map.get/2` and `Map.[key]` both return `nil`). Why is that and how can I retrieve the value out of the map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map syntax for string keys looks like:

```
%{"immediately" => [seconds: 1]}
```

Update your map to use that style first.

Also the function is missing a `:`

```
def expiration_presets, do: @expiration_presets_to_timeshift
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't notice the `key => value` vs `atom: value` crucial distinction !